# constraints in ruby-on-rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could someone describe what this is all about?

It's in the routing file:

```
match "photo", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
```

I can't understand it.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that the `photo` route will only be recognised and routed to a controller if the request contains the subdomain `admin`. For example, the Rails application would respond to a request of http://admin.example.org/photo, but not http://example.org/photo.

Comment: ok thanks. but which controller and index will this route use?

Comment: Whichever you want. For example: `match 'photo' => 'photos#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'admin' }`

Comment: but in the routing i posted there is no controller and action specified?

Comment: I think it's a poor example in the guide.

Comment: @John Topley. could i ask you how you saw my reply? did you get an instant notification when i made a new comment? cause i get no notifications when users are posting replies to my comments.

Comment: I didn't get an instant notification, but I was looking at this question and saw that you'd replied.

Answer (score 1):

One our guys [posted this today](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/) which describes how you could reuse the same routes with different contexts (in this case whether the user is logged in)

For instance if you create a simple class to evaluate true/false:

```
class LoggedInConstraint < Struct.new(:value)
  def matches?(request)
    request.cookies.key?("user_token") == value
  end
end
```

You can then use the evaluator in the routes to determine what routes apply:

```
root :to => "static#home", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(false)
root :to => "users#show", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(true)
```

Obviously you can design the constraints to your needs, but Steve described a couple different variants.